# Ignore JsonMediaTypeFormatter for a specific endpoint in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using asp.NET web api. In the WebApiConfig file, I have added following code for JSON formatter;

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
             //Support camel casing
            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().FirstOrDefault();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }
     }
```

This piece of code, serialize and supports camel casing for data across all endpoints in my application.

Is there any setting or attribute by which I can turn off this serializer for a specific endpoint?